# shrinking surfaceview to be in a box

Tags: java, android, surfaceview

I would like to change the current `SurfaceView` in my app from

[image: current surfaceview look]

to

[image: wanted surfaceview look]

Is there a way to do this without using `main.xml` at all?

I'm trying to code the GUI in run-time. I can achieve the current `SurfaceView` (top picture) by overriding `onMeasure()` and using `setMeasuredDimension()`, but I would like to achieve the bottom picture. The green area is the rest of the screen.

EDIT:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) 
{
    this.setMeasuredDimension(500, 300);
    param.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
}
```

Comment: What Layout are you using, what code do you already have?

Comment: I'm using FrameLayout. But I don't want to modify the main.xml because I would like to learn how to do this in runtime. I'm basing my code off the Qualcomm AR SDK and can't post all of it. The most important method I used to implement this is the onMeasure(), otherwise the SurfaceView would be fullscreen. `@Override
   protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) 
   {this.setMeasuredDimension(500, 300); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the `android:layout_gravity`-attribute to center your View in the Layout?

The corresponding class would be [`FrameLayout.LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.LayoutParams.html), possible gravity's are listed [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html). The code could then look something like this:

```
FrameLayout f = new FrameLayout(this);
ImageView test = new ImageView(this);
f.addView(test, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(500, 300, Gravity.CENTER));
```

Comment: For some reason my app keeps crashing when I tried to insert those lines in my app. There are too many lines of code for me to post on this site. I did try using gravity, like ` @Override
 protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) 
 {
  this.setMeasuredDimension(500, 300);
  param.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
 } `
but it still had the same effect. Is that how you could use it too?

Comment: If you say you create the whole Layout in code, this will take place in the `onCreate()`-method, I guess. You should then simply add the `LayoutParams` to your View you want to display in the `FrameLayout`.